# Hide part of the GUITexture in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, gui

I have a Health Bar in my **Unity** game and it's implemented as a `GUITexture` with gradient image from red to green.

[image]

Now I can reduce it's width from max width to 0, but is still scaled gradient.

```
public void UpdateHealthBar(int hitPoints) {
    healthBar.pixelInset = new Rect(
        healthBar.pixelInset.x, healthBar.pixelInset.y,
        3* hitPoints, healthBar.pixelInset.height);
}
```

[image]

But I want to hide (make transparent) the right part of this health bar in game progress.

[image]

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What about adding an image over top of it (that appears the same as the background)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via script, using [GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords.html)

This lets you clip-out a rectangle of the texture you want to draw onto the screen.

For instance (within an OnGUI() method)....

```
float healthFraction = ((float)hitPoints)/maxHitPoints;

Rect screenRect = new Rect(xPosition, yPosition, healthFraction * width, height);
Rect textureRect = new Rect(0, 0, healthFraction, 1);

GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(screenRect, texture, textureRect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're using `NGUI`, you can use `UISlider` for this. It'll automatically handle vertical, horizontal and radial progression using part of the image.